# QFileDialog opening two dialogs

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qfiledialog

I want to store a selected file's location as a string in Python. I am trying to use QFileDialog to accomplish this, I have:

```
self.filedialog = QtGui.QFileDialog(self)
self.filedialog.show()
filepath = str(self.filedialog.getOpenFileName())
```

This opens two QFileDialog windows. Interestingly, one of the windows does not inherit the 'style' of my GUI, set my setStyle, but does return the filepath string. The other QFileDialog does inherit the style, but can not return the filepath string. I have found the [QFileDialog documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qfiledialog.html#setDirectory) helpful, but have not been able to create a QFileDialog box that both produces the filepath string, and inherits the style of my GUI. What mistake am I making?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually created 2 windows.

The function `QFileDialog.getOpenFileName` is static, meaning that it creates its own `QFileDialog` object, shows the window, waits for the user to select a file and returns the choosen filename.

You should only need that line:

```
filepath = str(QFileDialog.getOpenFileName())
```

If you set the style at the application level (with `QApplication.setStyle`), it might be applied to the window if you use the non-native dialog:

```
filepath = str(QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(options=QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog)))
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked brilliantly. DontUseNativeDialog allowed the QFileDialog object to inherit the style, and when I added _self_ as the first argument to the getOpenFileName call, it inherited my gui's style sheet as well. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

`getOpenFileName` is a convenience function that ["creates a modal file dialog"](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qfiledialog.html#getOpenFileName). That's why you're getting the second dialog.

Use `filedialog.exec()` to show the dialog and `fileDialog.selectedFiles()` to get the filename.

Comment: Thanks Mark - getting rid of getOpenFileName fixed the two window issue. I'm still having difficulty returning the selected file's location string.

filedialog.exec() is not a viable function call for the filedialog object, but if I leave it as filedialog.show(), filedialog.selectedFiles() only returns the path of my current directory as a string.

Answer (score -1):

exec is a reserved word in python, you must use exec_().

```
dialog = QFileDialog(self)
dialog.exec_()
for file in dialog.selectedFiles():
    print file
```